# i want to Delete where id=$POST['id'] in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My code for delete entry is this but its not doing anything

HTML

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="">
    Id <input type="text" class="txt" name="id" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="delete" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
global $wpdb;

if ( isset ( $_POST['id'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['id']  ))
{
    $wpdb->query("DELETE " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'");
}
```

Comment: Why do you use **{}** in front of **$_POST['id']**

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon If you are talking about in the string it is because when using an array with a key, you have to wrap the entire thing in `{` `}` tags otherwise it will treat `$_POST` as the variable and `['id']` as a plain string.

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon It is correct.

Comment: Do you even know if the code executes>

Comment: Will be fine to inject some mysql there..

Comment: last question was same but only it was upate. Now delete.... Next insert probably?

Comment: @itachi Let him be happy!

Comment: Please add at least a check to make sure that $_POST['id'] is an int. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: Since you're new to PHP/SQL, **please pay heed to** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are checking for id in WHERE clause, you need not wrap it in quotes, and you are missing FROM in your delete statement, so standard way would be:
And do some filtering of POST data before inserting into database , like doing:

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
if( $id > 0 ) {
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id=".$_POST['id']);
}
```

Comment: -1 Please either 1) write acceptably safe code *and/or* 2) clearly state the issue(s) with the provided code. **Answers like this just continue the promotion of *bad, unsafe code*.**

Comment: i guess adding some comment along with the answer made it clear then before... !

Comment: The quotes (or lack thereof) aren't the problem. The [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is :( Here are [some practical demonstrations](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) and solutions.

Comment: @Sudhir you clearly copied my own answer because I made the same typo. you should be ashamed of yourself :( it is `id=".$_POST['id']."` not  `id=".$_POST['id']`

Comment: @shnisaka look carefully i dont have single quotes in id='"... where do you see it...?

Answer (score 1):

that is how I usually do it:

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."')
```

Comment: is this work surely?? `id=.'"$_POST['id']"'."` or should be `id='".$_POST['id']."'`

Answer (score 1):

In oder to avoid confusion like this, I always use `sprintf()` where I need to concatenate strings

Change:

```
global $wpdb;
if ( isset ( $_POST['id'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['id']  )) {
    $wpdb->query("DELETE " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'");
}
```

to:

```
global $wpdb;

if ( isset ( $_POST['id'] ) )) {    

   $wpdb->query(sprintf("DELETE %stutorial  WHERE id='%s'", PRO_TABLE_PREFIX, $_POST['id']));
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1) You're vulnerable to SQL injection
2) Once you've used `isset()` to determine if the key of `$_POST['id']` actually isn't `NULL`, you don't need to check if its empty via `empty()`

**Update**

You should really test `$_POST['id']` if its valid. I'd suggest you to implement a function, like, `is_id_valid()`

```
function is_id_valid(&$id){ //<-- IMPORTANT, Argument should be a reference 

  if ( ! isset($id) ){
     return false;
  }

  if ( empty($id) ){
    return false;
  }

  // add this if you expect $id to be a numeric value
  // otherwise just ignore - do not add
  if ( ! is_numeric($id) ){
    return false;  
  }

  //it's also a good to validate the length 
  if ( strlen($id) > ... && strlen($id) < ... ){
     return false;
  } 

  //seems like all tests passed
  return true;
}
```

Then you would use it, like

```
if ( is_id_valid($_POST['id']) !== false ){
   ....
}
```

Warning: It's still vulnerably to SQL injection

Comment: @GabrielSantos I meant it comes down to `E_NOTICE`

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand you.

Comment: The correct should be `if (!empty($_POST['id']))) {` because form will send ever the `id` index, but, with empty value if nothing is typed.

Comment: @GabrielSantos you're right, but it will throw a `E_NOTICE` then, while `isset()` won't

Comment: Why the `E_NOTICE` if form index will be always defined, even you post a full or empty form?

Comment: Yes, in that case if `form index will always be defined` and only, `empty()` makes more sense. But in general, it's better to ensure if it does actually exists if we're going to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: In general is better to check if is set and not empty, or, when you know it is defined, verify if not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote around `post['id']`:

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id={$_POST['id']}")
```

OR

```
echo $query = "DELETE " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . " tutorial  WHERE id =".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$wbpd->query($query);
```

Comment: you escape the string with `mysql_`, but then use PDO to execute the query. (facepalm)

Comment: @user1890857: try to echo the query. is query is building correctly?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: wbpd
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

Comment: @user1890857 don't remove `global $wpdb;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'");
```

**PS: Go overthere and accept one answer who helped you most. And here too! :P**

Comment: @user1890857 - You must accept answers in order for us to give you the right codes.. and this one, although its working is wrong.

Comment: Just think about help someone. More reputation will not grant you a reward.

Comment: @Gabriel Santos - Well if someone is to lazy or whatever to press one button in exchange for 20 mins help (this is 3rd time).. I think that person deserves everything else but help. Thx for nice words though ;)

Comment: He may be lazy or you may have not the solution. I understand you (:

Comment: @Gabriel Santos - Yes. That is the thing for sure :D

Comment: @user1890857 No, you are not lazy, sorry if you understood wrong. Re-read the comments above.

Comment: @user1890857 - You are lazy because you are not rewarding people who are helping you with accepting their answers. That is a point of this domain. And it is important because someone, who has problem same as you will see which answer helped you to solve that problem. When you receive good codes, click on "correct answer" and thats it! So simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:-

```
global $wpdb;

if ( isset ( $_POST['id'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['id']  ))
{
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id=".$_POST['id']);
}
```

Comment: it deleting after submit 2nd time why?

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: when i enter the id in text field and then enter on submitt button its do nothing in first time

Comment: it deletes after second time when i press submit button

Comment: It means, when you submit first time, the "id" is not submitted. Check how you are handling form submission.

Comment: it executes the query after second time

Comment: Please either 1) write safe code *or* 2) clearly state the issue(s) with the provided code

Answer (score 0):

```
give some action path to the form
```

html

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="give some actions">
Id <input type="text" class="txt" name="id" /><br />
<input type="submit" id="delete" value="delete"/>
```

php

```
global $wpdb;

if ( isset ( $_POST['id'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['id']  ))
{
  $id=stripslashes_deep($_POST['id']);
  $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM " . PRO_TABLE_PREFIX . "tutorial  WHERE id=$id");
}
```